# Нужна помощь с составление генетического алгоритма

Tags: алгоритм

Задача: Существует 5 проектов. Дается 5 тестов по 5 различным предметам. В каждом тесте есть 5 вопросов. Пользователи проходят тесты, и на основании их ответов формируется таблица в которой указывается 0 либо 1, т.е. правильно ответил на вопрос или нет. Нужно пользователей распределить по проектам на основании их ответов. В каждом проекте может быть по 5 человек. Не пойму как нужно проводить скрещивание чтобы получались потомки, ведь по сути у нас есть только фиксированные данные, и мы их изменять не можем, и создавать новых участников.

Была идея что нужно просто брать в качестве гена все ответы по одному тесту, и уже применять ГА к каждому тесту отдельно. Т.е. к примеру для каждого проекта есть определенная оценка того, сколько нужно набрать по каждому тесту. И применять ГА уже к самому тесту.

Comment: @rdorn спасибо, теперь понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если результатом работы алгоритма должно быть распределение людей по проектам, то вот эти распределения и нужно скрещивать, чтобы на выходе получить оптимальное по заданным критериям распределение. А результаты тестов нужны для оценки получаемых в процессе работы ГА распределений.